# Reduce memory consumption

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm currently using this code to analyze webcam frames:

```
int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    if (!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 15);

    std::vector<cv::Mat> images(9000);
    for (framenumb = 0; framenumb < 9000; ++framenumb) 
    {
        images[framenumb].create(480, 640, CV_8UC3);
    }
    for (framenumb = 0; framenumb < 9000; ++framenumb)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame;
        if (frame.empty()) break; // end of video stream
        if (waitKey(1) == 27) break; // stop capturing by pressing ESC 
        frame.copyTo(images[framenumb]);
        imshow("webcam", images[framenumb]);
    }
    //We can then process the captured frames
```

However, it leads to insufficient memory error:

```
OpenCV Error: Insufficient Memory (failed to allocate xyz bytes) in unknown function, file 
..\..\opecv\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp line 52.
```

Is there a way for me to avoid this? Thanks a lot in advanced!

Edit: Thanks for the all constructive feedback everyone! I guess all I can do for now is to change my approach to the problem. What I tried to accomplish was to take average of every 15 frames. For example: with 9000 frames, I will have 600 average pictures. Thus, I created a vector of 9000 images and use counter to achieve that.This is the code i used later:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++)
            {
                Mat avgImg(480, 640, CV_32FC3, Scalar());
                for (framenumb = 15 * i; framenumb < (15 * i) + 15; ++framenumb)
                {
                    cv::accumulate(images[framenumb], avgImg);
                }
                //stacking every 15 images into a single image
                avgImg = avgImg / 15;
                avgImg.convertTo(avgImg, CV_8UC3);
                char filename[80];
                sprintf(filename, "C:/AvgPics/test_%d.jpeg", framenumb);
                imwrite(filename, avgImg);
```

So is there a way for me to specify opencv to take average of every 15 images without having to use a 9000-image vector?

Comment: 9000 images might require a lot of memory.  I suggest holding fewer images, or reducing the size of each image as stored in the `cv::Mat` type.

Comment: I am definitely on board with @nobar, and also why do you have exactly the same two for loops?
Also, for your code's good, **Mat frame** can be declared at the outside of the for loop.

Comment: 640 * 480 * 3 bytes per frame * 9000 frames is around eight gigabytes.

Comment: Title is misleading - it is not `vector` which uses the memory, it's the object within it. I will edit the title.

Answer (score 7):

Compile as 64 bits. 8 GB is not excessive, but 32 bits programs are limited to 4GB at best. (I assume you do have sufficient RAM - at least 12 GB total). OpenCV supports 64 bits.

Comment: Delayed calling `create` until *just* before calling frame.copyTo(images[framenumb]), that would probably same memory in the case that it isn't needed.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to find a way to treat your frames without open them all at the same time.

I don't really know OpenCV syntax, but it seems that 9000 images of 480*640 pixels are opened, which require, assuming 3 bytes per pixel, a memory of 9000*480*640*3 bytes, i.e. 8 GB. That is not easy to treat with a standard computer with "classic quantity" of RAM.

If the treatment is sequential and doesn't require to open all frames simultaneously, the best thing to do is to adapt the treatment to do it sequentially frame by frame.

Comment: Virtual memory with a 64-bit program should handle 8gb fine.  This machine has 32GB physical memory.  That's not excessive